# Converting parent class to child class and parsing its parameter?

Tags: asp.net, inheritance

I am currently situation in which I have an empty parent class

```
public class Parent
{

}
```

for which my different child class inherit

```
public class ChildTypeA : Parent
{
   public int Age {get; set}
}

public class ChildTypeB: Parent
{
   public int Height {get; set}

}

public class ChildTypec:  Parent
{
   public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

Each child class has its own attribute which makes it unique.

The parent class is part of two classes

```
public class OutwardManner
{
  public Parent parent {get; set;}
}


public class InwardManner
{
  public Parent parent {get; set;}
}
```

I could for instance create an instance of the class `OutwardManner`, and define a parent for at as such

```
OutwardManner parentTypeA = new OutwardManner{
  parent = new ChildTypeA{
    Age = 4
  }
}
```

I would then like to create a mapping function capable of mapping my OutwardManner instance to an InwardManner for this I then create an Extension to both my classes so I can map between them..

```
public static OutwardManner MapToOut(this InwardManner inward)
{
    return inward(z => new AttributeView()
    {
         parent = z.parent 
    });
}
```

so when i do a

```
var parentTypeAIn = parentTypeAOut.MaptoIn()
```

the Parent within `parentTypeAIn` - or don't have any values - or the endpoint which receives this as a JSON is empty

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "print"?  Are you using ToString()?  The default ToString implementation just prints the class name; you need to override ToString for each class for it to print something unique.  Note that most automatic string conversions in .NET, such as string interpolation, use ToString internally.

Comment: Also, some C# tips:  The convention in C# is for all class names and public members to be PascalCased.

Comment: I added some info @N8allan

Comment: what are you trying to do with it? Maybe there's a more efficient way to achieve what you want, because now there's only 1 way that i see - implementing 3 virtual properties in the Parent class and then overriding them in Child classes. But each Child class is gonna inherit all the properties and they won't be unique

Comment: I am doing an extension capable of mapping the variable from one to another - but once I return it is empty? @steak_Overcooked

Comment: @Something i posted an answer, check it. That should help

Comment: @steak_Overcooked I specified my scenario a bit.. 

The return is important as the Endpoint reads this as a JSON and get an empty string rather the Age definition

Answer (score 0):

You need to override ToString() in order for anything to be printed.  For example:

```
public class ChildTypeA : Parent
{
    public int Age {get; set}
    public override string ToString()
        => $"Age: {Age}";
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding - Its not a console.writeline I was thinking of, but just returning in general..  when I return the value I get nothing?

Answer (score 0):

Your parent class doesn't have any fields in it so when you upcast your instance there're no fields. You could define 3 virtual properties but then all your child classes are gonna inherit them all. Try another approach with interfaces:

```
 interface IInterface1
    {
        int Height { set; get; }
    }
    interface IInterface2
    {
        int Age { set; get; }
    }
    interface IInterface3
    {
        string Name { set; get; }
    }

    class Realization : IInterface1, IInterface2, IInterface3
    {
        public int Height { set; get; }
        public int Age { set; get; }
        public string Name { set; get; }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IInterface2 instance = new Realization();
            Console.WriteLine(instance.Age);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I understand the difference, but you can't do it the way you try to. You want your_type instances to have different interfaces depending on what, let's say "method", was used to create them, but there's no chance you are doing it upcasting them to the same type. This is what interfaces are for actually - to control the behavior of an object and provide a certain set of methods, fields etc.

Comment: I idea was to do it like that to avoid having an `OutwardManner` class with too many variables which only would be used for certain cases.